# Argument value in C immutable?

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

I have the following code:

```
void func(uint8 *var) {
    uint8 tempvar;

    if (var)
        var = &tempvar;

    *var = 0;
}
```

I call the function using:

```
func(NULL);
```

The code gives a segmentation fault at the line "*var = 0;" because var still points to the memory address 0x0. I don't understand why my assignment to a temporary variable did not work!

Comment: "why my assignment to a temporary variable did not work". Well, it dos not work becuse you explicitly asked the program to *skip* that assignment if `var` is originally null. Your `if` condition says exactly that.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - Well, it's a local variable within the scope and I am only using it within the scope. The parameter is a single pointer and a change in address doesn't modify the caller variable. Hence, there is no variable accessed outside its scope.

Comment: Already got it ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you omitted the `!`. You are testing whether the variable exists, but you should test whether it *doesn't* exist: `if (!var) ...`

To expand a bit further... `var` is of type `uint8 *`, thus var itself is a pointer. By writing `if (var)` you are testing if that pointer is not NULL. In pseudo-code, your code says:

```
if (the var pointer already exists)
    assign a new pointer to it (make it point to somewhere else)
```

But if it doesn't exist (if it points to NULL), you leave it alone. You can verify this using a debugger or a simple print statement. Thus you end up at the assignment with a null-pointer, and crash your program.

Comment: Doesn't if(var) translate to if(var == 0) which is equivalent to if(var == NULL)?

Comment: Nope. `if (...)` is a test whether something is true. Zero (NULL) values promote to false; all other values to true. Anyway, just try it!

Comment: @H.Guijt this is not the reason for sure, if (NULL) is false

Comment: Well, if you are certain about that I guess you must be right. I mean, I've only been programming in C++ since the nineties, what do I know...

Comment: @AhmedSaid Yes, `if (NULL)` is false, which means that `var = &tempvar` is not executed.

Comment: @Kunal Kapoor: `if(var)` translates to `if(var != 0)`, which is the exact opposite of what you seemed to assume.

Comment: Weird that I was confused about a code construct I've been using for years! Thanks guys..